# How to get content of any file that is having authentication with it in php?

Tags: php, xml, file-get-contents

I am reading one xml file from my uploads folder with file_get_contents and its working for me.
Now i want to read xml file from another server that is having authentication to read file.

so, how can i read that file. please help me .

My current code to read xml file :

```
    $xml = file_get_contents('uploads/data.xml');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $xml_array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1);
```

I am having one url and Username/Password to get xml data from it.

I want something like this but as this comes with authentication part am not able to read file.

```
$xml = file_get_contents('https:dummyurl/feed.xml'); //some url and xml file.
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xml_array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1);
```

Comment: Do you have valid credentials to authenticate you on that remote site? If you do then I'd suggest using cURL to fetch the XML.

Comment: yes i have credentials. @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: Is it http Basic Authentication, or some other scheme?

Comment: Use curl o make the authentication request and save the cookie. The following request would be to download the XML which you can process on your main server as you do here or with DOMDocument. If the `other` server has SSL then you need to take care that you use a valid `cacert.pem` file

Comment: How is the `Authentication` dealt with - is it a regular login form or is it to be done using an Authentication header with the request?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not authenticate using `file_get_contents`, to retrieve a response from a server which requires authentication you will need to use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl). Depending on the authentication type, you may need to send specific headers, or in some cases even make separate requests (one to authenticate and  retrieve some token, and then one to request resource with that token).